# OpenLayers 3 - zoom to specific level after animation

Tags: javascript, animation, openlayers-3

I've created a map in Openlayers 3 that is based off the "doBounce" (pan & bounce animation) from this sample script (goo.gl/YoR7Ta). Here's  [FIDDLE #1](http://jsfiddle.net/neviln/ggfpmutq/)  for the basic doBounce animation.

What I'm aiming for is to have the map also do a zoom animation to a specific zoom level AFTER the "doBounce" animation. Each location will have a different zoom level. For example, when I click on "North Coast", it does the "doBounce" animation, then does a zoom animation to zoom level of 10. And when I click "Fraser River", it does "doBounce", then a zoom animation to zoom level of 12.

I've spent the past few days trying to figure out how to do it & have searched through google & stackoverflow with no luck.

The best I could come up with was putting together this hacky  [FIDDLE #2](http://jsfiddle.net/neviln/wcn8vt0g/)  that at least lets me do some kind of zoom animation afterwards ...but it's not quite what I want.

Here's my modified "doBounce" script from the second fiddle:

```
function doBounce(location) {
    var duration = 2500;
    var start = +new Date();

    //REMOVE COMMENT FROM NEXT LINE TO SEE TEMP FIX SO ZOOM OCCURS EACH TIME
    //map.getView().setResolution(500);

    var bounce = ol.animation.bounce({
        duration: duration,
        resolution: view.getResolution() * 5,
        start: start
    });

    var pan = ol.animation.pan({
        duration: duration,
        source: view.getCenter(),
        start: start
    });

    var zoom = ol.animation.zoom({
        resolution: view.getResolution(),
        duration: 800,
        easing: ol.easing.linear,
      start: start + 2500
    });

    map.beforeRender(bounce, pan);
    view.setCenter(location);

    setTimeout(function() {
        map.beforeRender(zoom);
        view.setResolution(250);
    }, 2510);
}
```

I used a timeout to delay the zoom animation until the "deBouce" animation has finished. This finally allowed me to have a zoom animation but it would only happen on the first click. The following clicks would not show a zoom animation (I assume because `ol.animation.bounce()` returns the same resolution it started with).

To fix this, I added `view.setResolution(500);` at the start of the function so that it changes the resolution. This way, at least the zoom animation would work on each click. You can see what I mean by running the fiddle and then removing the commented line and running it again.

Is there a way to have each location smoothly zoom into a specific zoom level after the "doBounce" animation?

I'm fairly new to Javascript & Openlayers so any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `map.beforeRender(bounce, pan, zoom);` ?

Comment: don't change the resolution, change the zoom level http://jsfiddle.net/joherro3/wcn8vt0g/7/

Comment: @grateful - Yes, I tried but it seems to trigger the zoom animation at the same time as the other animations, causing it to create an entire different animation that still doesn't result in a different zoom level. I think that's because the bounce animation and zoom animation both need to use `getResolution`. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neviln/wcn8vt0g/9/) trying that method.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo - How would I make it so each location has a different zoom level. And also, when playing around with your variation, I noticed that if you trigger the first animation, then manually zoom in to the map and then click to trigger a second animation, it doesn't zoom out gradually anymore. It just jumps to the proper zoom level and then pans to the new location. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neviln/wcn8vt0g/10/) (I adjusted the initial zoom level and your zoom level to help show what I was referring to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could structure this flow chaining (calling in sequence) your functions with a promise helper library like [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). It can be like this:

```
function flyTo(location) {
  var final_zoom = 12,
      initial_zoom = 4;

  zoom(initial_zoom)
    .then(function() {
      console.info('Zoomed Out!');
      return panTo(location);
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.info('Panned to ... ');
      return zoom(final_zoom);
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log('done!');
    });
}
```

Or shorter:

```
function flyTo(location) {
  var final_zoom = 12,
      initial_zoom = 4;

  zoom(initial_zoom)
    .then(panTo.bind(null, location))
    .then(zoom.bind(null, final_zoom))
    .then(function() {
        console.log('done!');
    });
}
```

Other functions:

```
function zoom(zoom_level) {
  var duration = 500;
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var zoom = ol.animation.zoom({
    duration: duration,
    resolution: view.getResolution()
  });

  map.beforeRender(zoom);
  view.setZoom(zoom_level);

  Q.delay(duration).then(deferred.resolve);
  return deferred.promise;
}

function panTo(location) {
  var duration = 1500;
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var pan = ol.animation.pan({
    duration: duration,
    source: view.getCenter()
  });

  map.beforeRender(pan);
  view.setCenter(location);

  Q.delay(duration)
    .then(deferred.resolve); // <---- here's where things happen
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/ve4r3xd1/))

Comment: The smoothness & flow of your animation script is amazing, thank you!. I spent the last 45 minutes trying to understand how the scripting works, as it was a lot to grasp for someone who's new to Javascript. Is there anyway to make the "final_zoom" different for each location?

Comment: Yes, see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/ve4r3xd1/).

Comment: You sir, are amazing! Thank you very much! One last question if you don't mind....with this promise helper library, would I be able to implement code that drops a marker once the animation has zoomed in and then removes it when the next location is clicked? If so, where would I place that code? Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, sure. [Fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/ve4r3xd1/). You're welcome.

Comment: I wish I could give you more points! Thanks a million Jonatas!